# Search url in a text using 'like' in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, sql-like

I tried to search 'http://www.example.com/' keyword in a string. I'm using following code snippets for that.

First code

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT pa.id
                FROM qbnk_answer a
                INNER JOIN qbnk_question AS q
                ON q.id = a.question_id 
                INNER JOIN qbnk_assessment_question_xref AS aqx
                ON q.id = aqx.question_id
                INNER JOIN qbnk_published_assessment AS pa
                ON aqx.assessment_id = pa.assessment_id 
    where a.label LIKE "%http://www.example.com/%"';

    $command = $connection->createCommand($query);
    $results = $command->queryAll();
```

Second code

```
$query = new Query();
    $query = $query->select(['pa.id'])
            ->from(['a' => Answer::tableName()])
            ->innerJoin(['q' => Question::tableName()], "a.question_id = q.id")
            ->innerJoin(['aqx' => AssessmentQuestionXref::tableName()], "aqx.question_id = q.id")
            ->innerJoin(['pa' => PublishedAssessment::tableName()], "aqx.assessment_id = pa.assessment_id")
            ->where(['like', 'a.label', 'http://www.example.com/' ]);
    $command = $connection->createCommand($query);
    $command->execute();
```

This both codes are working fine in my local windows environment. But when I'm moving them to server which is running linux not working.
But it working if I remove '/' (forward slashes) from searching keyword.

Is there any solution for that will be highly helpful for me

Comment: Are you getting any error or it it now fetching records?

Comment: No errors and no records. empty array returned.

Comment: Change your last where condition like this : ->where('a.label LIKE "%http://www.example.com/%"');

Comment: Yii2 directly supports raw queries

Comment: @Yasin I need http:// as well. I tried raw queries as well. Both versions are in the quotation